# Throwing on unwrapping nil optional

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, swift2, option-type

Consider the following code:

```
enum MyErrorType:ErrorType {
    case BadTimes
}

var mightHaveAValue: String?

do {

    if let value = mightHaveAValue {
        // do stuff with value
    } else {
        throw MyErrorType.BadTimes
    }

    // do stuff with NSFileManager using mightHaveAValue which might throw

} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

...in which I have a large do/try/catch block. In this instance the error handling will be the same, whether `mightHaveAValue` is empty or something bad happens with `NSFileManager` later on. So it makes sense to re-use the error handling code.

Is this the cleanest approach going in Swift2, or is there some way I can automatically throw/catch on unwrapping an optional with no value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks ok, but it's even better with `guard let` instead of `if let` because it lets you use the unwrapped value in the main `do` block instead of having to work inside an `if let` branch. You can also use several `catch` branches to handle different error types.

```
do {

    guard let value = mightHaveAValue else {
        throw MyErrorType.BadTimes
    }

    // do stuff with value

} catch let error as MyErrorType {
    // handle custom error
} catch let error as NSError {
    // handle generic NSError
}
```

There is no automatic way to handle unwrapping optionals, you have to use one of the many known ways: `if let`, `guard let`, nil coalescing, etc.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason I had wrongly assumed `guard let` could only be used at the top of a function, just because that's what all the example use cases seem to be about.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe just use an extension like this

```swift
extension Optional {

    func throwing() throws -> Wrapped {
        if let wrapped = self {
            return wrapped
        } else {
            throw NSError("Trying to access non existing value")
        }
    }
}
```